# Is it possible to add a variable in the getview adapter function by overriding it?

Tags: android, kotlin, adapter, getview

How to refer to adapter in the getview (of a listview)  with this google syntax :

```
fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
    return (convertView ?: layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, parent, false)).apply {
        // … bind content from position to convertView …
        //personal comment : "this" does not refer to adapter
    }
}
```

Indeed, after the .apply, I have to call adapter in order to make an `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

With a "classic syntax", adapter could be called thanks to "this", that is impossible with google syntax.

"Classic syntax"

```
fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {

....

//"this" (refers to adapter)

return convertView
}
```

So is it possible to overriding the getview function to add variable in the signature ? Else, what is the solution of my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.also { ... }` instead of `.apply { ... }`

Comment: Thx for the tips :)

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to mark it as the correct answer if that's what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, you can:

Write your `getView(...)` function same as adapters, with additional parameter

call your `getView()` in adapter overridden `getView(...)` pass your argument what you want.

Comment: Thx you but when I add some parameter it is written that « the function overrides nothing. »